# Accepted answers without upvotes

Tags: discussion

Every now and then we see an [accepted answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/31495/3920) without any upvotes. In view of an upvote meaning "this answer is useful" shouldn't there at least be an upvote from OP? Shouldn't one be added on OP's behalf by the system if OP doesn't upvote?

(linked answer has no upvotes at the moment I'm writing this. May have some later on)

Comment: The asker possible does not yet have rep to upvote. As a non-expert with no rep it does not make sense to give an upvote when they have yet to receive validation from the community. If they are an expert their question probably received many upvotes anyway.

Answer (score 3):

That's an answer of mine. I would have appreciated the upvote, and it would have made sense, since like you say an answer has to be at least useful to accept it.

But the upvote isn't really needed. While answers are ranked by votes the accepted answer always tops the list anyway, even without upvotes. I see no need to extort the upvote from the asker.

Comment: This has happened a few times to me too.  It seems a bit strange, but no big deal really.  I don't think this is anything worth changing the system for.  Any cure will likely be worse than this very mild disease.

Comment: @Olin - Kortuk has a point about not having enough rep, I hadn't thought of that. I believe they need 15. May still take some time if they only have bad questions and no answers, though :-)